# Remove Out[x] for Jupter notebooks converted to HTML with nbconvert

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I find myself often needing to convert long jupyter notebooks to `.html` using `jupyter nbconvert`.

I share these notebooks with a wide audience and have been asked about the `out[x]`a few times. That is the following:

[image]

I wanted to remove these, but coudn't find a good way of doing this.

I created a hacky solution, but I'm looking for something less hacky.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to directly edit the `.html` source code.
Specifically, the Out[x] portion has the following class

```
div.output_prompt {
  color: #D84315;
}
```

Each instance of Out [x] can simply be made invisible with switching the color to white.
Automatically, this can be done with `sed`.

```
sed -i '/div\.output_prompt/ N;s/color: #D84315;/color: white;/' filename.html
```